# Is getting a specific bit of information from a mysql column possible?

Tags: php, mysql, string-parsing

Say I have a mysql table of names and one column has the following name inside it -

```
| id |         name            |
| 1  | "Robert Downey Junior"  |
```

and I only want to echo from this column part of the name: `"Downey"`

I know the most optimal way of doing this would be to have three separate columns for first name, second name and surname, however is it possible to extract just a part of that name if the full name was inside one column?

Note: I would like to point out that I would need the full name in another place and the easiest way to put the names into the database is the full name - as there are literally thousands of names.

Comment: Which part of the name do you want to return? You must be more specific here.

Comment: Are all the names formatted the same? EG: First Middle last ? Each with a space between each name?

Comment: just the middle name - `Downey` or any part of that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the names are formatted the same (First Middle Last, space separated), you can do:

```
$result = mysql_query( 'SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result);
$name = explode( ' ', $row['name']);
echo $name[1]; // "Downey"
```

Comment: This seems to be the only one not returning any errors and is working for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this in MySQL alone. I'd use PHP

```
$name = explode(" ", $result['name']);
echo "Hi, " . $name[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = mysql_query("select name from myDB");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $middlename = preg_match("#^[ ]+(?:Mrs|Mr)\.?[^ ]+ (.+) [^ ]+[ ]+$#i", row[0]);
   print_r($middlename[0]);
}
```

This will correctly parse middle names of people with multiple middle names, e.g:

```
Kelvin de la Cruz Gam-Jensen
```

will be

```
de la Cruz
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Just use the php explode function on the result of the query.  Explode on space and use the 2nd element of the resulting array. Which is 1 since the first array element is 0.

Assuming a working db_connect() function:

`$conn=db_connect();
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from table where id=1;
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $name_parts = explode(" ", $data["name"]);
    echo $name_parts[1];`

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php